# Drag and Drop in HTML5 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I have seen many questions related to this, including [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/thudfactor/6611441), but, I'm still having troubles implementing the functionality I want. I have put up the most trivial fiddle possible which also basically sums up my knowledge of manipulating styles and etc.

AFAIK the below fiddle only works in Google Chrome.

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: '#q1',
    over: function(e,ui) {
       $(ui.draggable).css({ cursor: 'copy' });
    },
    out:function(e,ui) {
       $(ui.draggable).css({ cursor: 'no-drop' });
    },
    activate: function(e,ui) {
       $(this).animate({ fill:rgb(255,0,0) }).text('Drop me here!');
    },
    deactivate: function(e,ui) {
       $(this).animate({ borderColor: 'gray' }).text('');
    }
});
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3s0zfu7/)

I want to have a draggable that consists of a disabled input box and I want to be able to drag the aforementioned input box into an SVG rectangle. Ideally, after dropping, the box should be slightly shrunken or, even better, replaced by a number.

Key issues:

1. The box is HTML and it's hard to change because its being generated in jQuery and on my problem it lives inside a div.
2. The rectangle also needs to be SVG.

Comment: Have you checked http://caniuse.com?

Comment: I did, but, got lost in the middle of it, because I know that FF won't allow me to drag input boxes simply by using the draggable=true. So I switched to Chrome. And I know that the boxes are draggable and that I see the ghost. What I need now is to be able to drop them on an svg drawing and change its style for example